# How to find a transparent icon in a picture?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, template-matching

I want to find this icon with transparent background

[image: small image]

in this image

[image: large image]

I tried the following code:

```py
import cv2
method = cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED

small_image = cv2.imread('icons/new/test.png')
large_image = cv2.imread('icons/example.png')

result = cv2.matchTemplate(small_image, large_image, method)

mn,_,mnLoc,_ = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

MPx,MPy = mnLoc

trows,tcols = small_image.shape[:2]

cv2.rectangle(large_image, (MPx,MPy),(MPx+tcols,MPy+trows),(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imshow('output',large_image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But, the result is as follows:

[image: result]

I think this is because my small image has transparent background. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please notice, that [`cv2.matchTemplate`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be) has a `mask` parameter, where you can set up a mask for the template, which would be the alpha channel of your template (small image). Further, keep in mind to feed image (large image) and template (small image) in that order to `cv2.matchTemplate`:

```py
result = cv2.matchTemplate(large_image, small_image[..., :3], method, mask=small_image[..., 3])
```

To preserve the alpha channel of your template (small image), use the [`cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80) flag in [`cv2.imread`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56):

```py
small_image = cv2.imread('icons/new/test.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

With these two changes, I get the desired output:

[image: Output]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
OpenCV:        4.5.2
----------------------------------------
```